# Is there a time dilation between my left and right arms?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Is there a time dilation between my left and right arms when walking? due to special relativity I guess Thanks

Comment: Yes, when they're in separate reference frames there will be a small time dilation. There is also a time dilation between your head and your feet due to gravity.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no time dilation. Both arms are part of your frame of reference.

Comment: You don't swing your arms when you walk?